# Solving a homogenous second order recurrence with polynomial coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, frobenius-method

How would I find a closed-form solution of a recurrence that I obtained from solving an ODE using Frobenius method?:

$(k+2)(k + 4)a_{k+2} - a_{k+1} + (k+2)a_k = 0$

given $a_0 = a$ and $a_1 = \frac{1}{3}a.$ I am fairly new to the topic. I have already searched for a pattern from the first few terms (I'm terrible at guessing games), tried substituting other series, using annihilators and generating functions. Various papers I have found on the topic seem to avoid examples of variable coefficients in recurrences of higher order than $1$.

May I ask for a method I should use, or perhaps why in my case there can't be a closed-form solution? I would also appreciate a few steps into the algorithm in question.

Equation in question: $x^2y'' + x(x^2-1)y'-xy=0$

EDIT: Upon evaluating denominators of the first few terms I plugged them into  OEIS, and obtained:

$a_k = \frac{2b_k}{k!(k+2)!}$

Using $b_k$ as a new substitution results in:

$b_{k+2} - b_{k+1} + b_k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)=0$

Comment: Mathematica is not able to find a closed form solution (for the ODE I mean)

Comment: Mathematica is not able to find a closed form solution for the recurrence either.

Comment: Maple 2017.3 solution for ODE:$$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{x}^{2}}}{\it HeunB}
 \left( 2,0,0,2\,\sqrt {2},1/2\,\sqrt {2}x \right) {x}^{2}+{\it \_C2}
\,{{\rm e}^{-1/2\,{x}^{2}}}{\it HeunB} \left( 2,0,0,2\,\sqrt {2},1/2\,
\sqrt {2}x \right) {x}^{2}\int \!{\frac {{{\rm e}^{1/2\,{x}^{2}}}}{{x}
^{3} \left( {\it HeunB} \left( 2,0,0,2\,\sqrt {2},1/2\,\sqrt {2}x
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x
$$